# Updating from objective c to swift - previous core data content not loading

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to migrate an app of mine that was using objective c to now use swift. I'm getting no errors but its not loading the information previously in the app. I've imported the old model into the new project

In the new app its loading the core data store using

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Medicine_Tracker")
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
}
```

and loaded in the view using the below. The NSLog results in Item Count: 0 whereas it should be Item Count: 2

```
struct MedicineView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Medicine.name, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Medicine>

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: MedicineDetailView(medicine: item)) {
                    Text("\(item.name ?? "Error")")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Medicines", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink(destination: MedicineAddView()) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            NSLog("Item Count: \(items.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

and the old app uses

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Medicine_Tracker" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Medicine_Tracker.sqlite"];
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: In your swift version you are using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` but you are not using CloudKit in the objective-c version, is this deliberate?

Comment: I’ve tried both with cloudkit and without and neither load the data. I’ve been able to swap between them previously in another app without issue as well

Comment: Would you mind showing full code mimicking the same settings? And then, you can change later to CloudKit if you want, but since it's not working, you are adding more "differences", it's harder to spot the error difference then... Doing multiples steps is better...

Comment: The only difference is NSPersistentCloudKitContainer is replaced by NSPersistentContainer